# Storing small data on a web application

Tags: database, database-design, widget, storing-data

I'm developing a portal. This portal have contents (articles, books...) and there are some widgets that take a selection of this contents (like featured articles) and show them in a determinate order.

I think that add a boolean "featured" and a field "order" to every content entry of the table of contents its excesive, specially because perhaps exists different types of being featured and, then, different orders.

Also, some widgets works with static data: There is one that shows a list of links. Of course, this could be a simple static page but the admin of the web have to be able to edit the links and then, this have to be stored dinamically somewhere.

If the solution is design special tables for this issues I dont know how to plan it, becuase my first approach is create a table "widget1_items" with a pair of fields, the id of the content and the order value. This for every widget, and something similar for the static widgets.

There is a better solution for this problem? Thank for your help and attention

Comment: Maybe you should use a CMS? Most of the popular ones have features or modules that might do this for you.

Comment: Suppose I can't for non-technical reasons in my work, but it will help know how the CMS store the info about small widgets, the place of the widgets, etc.